# -second dropdownlist change when first dropdownlist is selected-

Tags: asp.net

Hiyee..Now I'm stuck in changing the second dropdownlist. For example, first dropdownlist- select 2, second dropdownlist will change from 1,2,3,4 to  2,3,4,5,6. Other than cascading dropdownlist, it there anyother methods?...Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use server-side cascading to achieve this. Here's an example:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2007/07/21/Code-Snippet-Cascading-DropDownLists.aspx

What you are describing is effectively a cascade since the selection in the second DDL is determined by the selection in the first DDL.